# How to make the textbox scroll to bottom inside the update panel, when each time doing a postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to do, a live chatroom in a webpage which using asp.net c#. The technology I use the the timer and the asp.net textbox (not input textbox) and the update panel. Since the timer will keep doing the postback if I put inside any control in the webpage, so I put the timer into the update panel. However, since I want to doing a live chat system, the conversation must be scroll to the bottom each time I added a new conversation line. However , I encounter a problem which is, if I not calling the updatepanel.Update() , the update panel will not update, if I call the function, yes, it suppose to get the update, but the problem is, even I call the script of the

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ScrollTextbox", "document.getElementById('" + this.ConversationTextBox.ClientID + "').scrollTop = document.getElementById('" +
            this.ConversationTextBox.ClientID + "').scrollHeight;", true);
```

the script doesn't work because each time the panel get update, it will doing a postback in the update panel. this is the bug, each time the update panel doing a postback, the textbox will auto scroll to the most top.

If I call the javascript before updatepanel.Update(), once the update panel update, the textbox will be forced to top since it is a postback,

if I call updatepanel.Update() before javascript, the textbox will not able to update.

Comment: the problem is, each post back will force the textbox scroll to most top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the server will create a postback, in this case, you are required to call the scroll to bottom method from client side so it will not create a postback, hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use triggers to avoid all the controls in UpdatePanel update together.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="YourcontrolID" EventName="YourEventName" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Hope this help. ^^